# Retrieve product by handle with Shopify Javascript Buy SDK

Tags: javascript, shopify

I am implementing a Shopify Store into a WordPress theme and one thing I need for that is a way to query Shopify products with the product handle instead of ID as shown on their docs:

http://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk/api/classes/ShopClient.html#method-fetchProduct

The reason for this is what I want to have the single product view with a SEO friendly URL, built precisely from the product handle.

On Shopify's site someone mentions a non-documented way to achieve this, I couldn't however get it to work:
https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/how-do-i-query-for-a-product-using-its-handle-322118#comment-346792

Have anyone had luck with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [fetchQueryProducts()](http://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk/api/classes/ShopClient.html#method-fetchQueryProducts) is what you're looking for. As an example:

```js
var shopClient = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
  apiKey: 'my_key',
  myShopifyDomain: 'your_myshopify_domain',
  appId: 6
});

shopClient.fetchQueryProducts({handle: 'your_product_handle'}).then(function(products) {
  // Your product is at products[0] if successful
});
```

Comment: Oh wow, that actually works, even though I've been informed by Shopify it wouldn't :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to fetch product by handle.

```
client.product.fetchByHandle(handle).then(
        product => { // Your product },
        error => { // error },
)
```

Comment: Note, this is for v1 of the buy sdk.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way in the API that I know of to do this.  You may end up having to store a mapping of IDs to handles, and keep that mapping updated via webhooks.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case, currently waiting for feedback from Spotify but that's probably what I will end-up having to do, which sucks considering that the same problem will happen for categories too.